# ResourceDictionary Locator

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Is there a way to create a ResourceDictionary Locator.
Right now I have in xaml:

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Resources/StringResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

Where the code behind sets the list of dictionaries based on currentculture

I'd like to have

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <Locator "StringResources"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

Or something like that such that I don't have to modify each v.xaml.cs files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own ResourceDictionary:

```
public class ResourceDictionaryLocator : ResourceDictionary
{
    public ResourceDictionaryLocator()
    {
        switch (CurrentLocalization)
        {
            case "English":
                base.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Languages/English.xaml");
                break;

            case "French":
                base.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Languages/French.xaml");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then consume it like this:

```
<Application x:Class="TestingWPF.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingWPF"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <local:ResourceDictionaryLocator />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This is generally not done, however.  You can load different resource dictionaries at runtime.  Something like the following:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
```

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME, I made this locator listen to global language changed event and my entire app now changes from a dropdown. thank you for this elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `MarkupExtension` that will return the requested ResourceDictionary:

```cs
public class ResourceDictionaryLocator : MarkupExtension
{
    public string DictionaryName { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Logic to return the wanted ResourceDictionary
        if (DictionaryName == "...")
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then use it in xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:ResourceDictionaryLocator DictionaryName="StringResources" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if this is posible, but do you want to make that your application be 'Localizable'? Baybe this article could be helpful to you: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Resx_Localization/.